# immutable vs struct and type vs mutable struct in Julia

Tags: struct, types, julia

Let's define 4 different classes of points:

```
type PointType
    x
    y
end

mutable struct PointMut
    x
    y
end

immutable PointImmut
    x
    y
end

struct PointStruct
    x
    y
end
```

What is the difference between `PointType` and `PointMut`? Why would someone choose one over the other?

Also what is the difference between `PointImmut` and `PointStruct`?

I tend to believe that they are just synonyms, but I didn't find this stated explicitly, so I wonder if there is a subtle difference hidden somewhere.

Comment: ["In 0.6, immutable and type are still allowed as synonyms without a deprecation warning."](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md#language-changes-1)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`type` and `immutable` are valid up to julia 0.6, `mutable struct` and `struct` are the names of the same objects in julia 0.6 and forward. `mutable`in `mutable struct` means that the fields can change - which is actually fairly rarely used so being immutable is the default. `mutable struct`'s are slower than `struct`s.

Comment: that's because it's being deprecated. The fact that `type` and `immutable` ever existed will be something for the history books soon.